# Setting glyph spacing with mathspec

Tags: xetex, mathspec

I am using `xelatex` and the `mathspec` package to use the Calibri font found on recent Windows machines. The font metrics used to typeset italic characters are fine for text but not for math; glyphs often collide.

With `mathspec`, one can precede a character in math mode with `"` to increase its spacing. The characters in the figure below were typeset using

```
$f(x)$, $"f(x)$, $f'(x)$, $"f'(x)$, $e^{jx}$,$"e^{"jx}$.
```

[image]

While this works fine when one only has to use it infrequently, for a long document it becomes tedious. Is there a way to always use this corrected spacing without manually preceding every character of the alphabet with `"`?

Comment: Short answer: no. Longer answer: `mathspec` does its best in order to emulate math fonts, but if the fonts lack the necessary specifications for being used in math mode, it's a lost battle.

Comment: Bummer. I really like using alternate fonts but some of the math definitely looks wrong without tweaking. I was hoping there was a global setting I could use ... Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A “real” math font, such as those that can be used with `unicode-math`, has glyphs specially tailored for math fonts.

For instance with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

\textit{f} $f(x)$

\end{document}
```

the character used for the second “f” is U+1D453 MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL F in Latin Modern Math, which has the same shape as an italic “f” (the first one), but different side bearings and other metric parameters.

If you use `mathspec`, say with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}
\setmathfont(Latin){Hoefler Text}

\begin{document}

\textit{f} $f(x)$ $"f(x)$

\end{document}
```

you get

[image]

The package makes its best for getting decent output, but using glyphs not specially designed for a math font clashes with the rules of TeX's math mode, in particular when the letters are slanted.

Thus the `"f` trick is a “necessary evil”. You see that in some cases you need it, in others you don't: it depends on pairs of adjacent characters that are taken from different fonts. With `unicode-math` *the same font* is used, but this is not the main aspect; the relevant fact is that the math letters have special parameters.